# ASP.NET MVC Controller Action for Server sent events

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

How will an ASP.NET MVC Controller action look like when SSE is being used?

Typically the action would return a ActionResult but in the case of Server sent events since the connection should be kept open how will this be considered?

Comment: You might want to look at the PushStreamContent class and this example : http://forums.asp.net/t/1885055.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done by ASP.NET MVC action (just can't, don't try).

There is a transparent implementation of SSE for ASP.NET - [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). You can use it in ASP.NET MVC application with no issues.

Also since ASP.NET 4.5 there is a build in support for WebSockets but you must be running your application on IIS 8 and the client browser must also have built in WebSockets support (if I remember correctly this would be IE10, Chrome 13+, Firefox 7+, Safari 5+ and Opera 11+)

Comment: As long as [the method isn't actually returning anything, but writing directly to the response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35678190/111794), why not?